# Timestamping services authorities, utilizing Linked, hybrid and other than PKI schemes

Tags: timestamping

What are well respected [Cryptographic Timestamping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) authorities utilizing more sophisticated than just PKI (RFC 3161) schemes, like Linked, Linked and signed, distributed hash trees (maybe P2P?), hybrid ?

Is there any good resource (better than googling, what does not give information about how well service is respected).

I would love to use [*Keyless Signatures*](http://www.guardtime.com/signatures/) (different thank PKI schemes), preferably remaining reliable if PKI would be compromised (e.g. *Linked and signed*, distributed, hybrid, etc).

I know about such interesting approach:
http://www.guardtime.com/signatures/technology-overview/ ,
but I would like to used a few (for better reliability - to achieve tens of years reliability) different approaches.

Preferably those *well respected* timestamps to be legally respected (e.g. [Securo](http://securo.it/) "Conforms to EU and US federal standards)

Comment: related answers http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3731/1809 , http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3732/1809 about technology in general.

Comment: For interested readers [A survey of the problems of time-stamping or why it is necessary to have another time-stamping scheme](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1332099)