# A timestamping authority (digital notary)

Tags: signature, timestamping

Does there currently exist a free online service that accepts a file, hashes it, takes an authoritatively chosen timestamp (from one or more time services), signs these and sends this signed message back? E.g. a *digital notary*, but only with regards to the timestamp and not the validity of the content as legal notaries might be obligated to guarantee.

Such a service might have an extremely simple API: Simply `wget http://service/<checksum>` and receive a signed message containing one or more timestamps and the checksum. The emphasis would be on the type of authority who might make such a service.

**Edit:** Although the original question did not emphasise the following, the Bitcoin-based timestamping services provided below do not rely on one authority, but rather the entire Bitcoin network. They can be seen as tamper-proof and verifiable without the help of the service that helped you sign it!

Comment: Not exactly helpful, but you can try to stack type 0x40 PGP signature packets together in one PGP key. Problem is, I don't know of any implementation that creates type 0x40 keys.

Comment: [This service](http://www.itconsult.co.uk/stamper.htm) is a pretty popular one and has been up for a long time. It's not an "instant" API though, it uses emails and it seems to send your stamp at the end of the day.

Comment: I ended up reasking this at: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14139/trusted-timestamping-public-proof-that-i-knew-something-at-a-given-time-without because I hadn't found it before.

Comment: You can check tecxoft tsa (www.tecxoft.com/tsa.php), offers free signup, this TSA is compliant to RFC 3161. It is easy to integrate, good for PDF digital timestamps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you search on "timestamp", "timestamping", and "notary" on Crypto.SE and Security.SE, you'll find lots of references.  I've collected a number of timestamping services that were mentioned in one of those places; this should provide a number of companies and online services you can check out:

- http://www.proofofexistence.com/
- https://www.btproof.com/
- https://www.universign.eu/en/
- http://www.guardtime.com/
- http://securo.it/
- http://www.cryptostamp.net/
- http://www.itconsult.co.uk/stamper.htm
- https://www.globalsign.com/timestamp-service/

I cannot vouch for or endorse any of those.

See, for instance, the following questions on this site, and the following other resources:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/q/19184/971
- https://security.stackexchange.com/q/43995/971
- [How are timestamps verified?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1816/351)
- [Signature and Timestamp for Long Term Document Archival Question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3291/351)
- [Timestamping services authorities, utilizing Linked, hybrid and other than PKI schemes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3733/351)
- https://security.stackexchange.com/q/24458/971
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3161
- https://security.stackexchange.com/q/32493/971
- https://security.stackexchange.com/q/47289/971

Happy reading!

Answer (score 7):

Several [certificate authorities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Authority) operate [RFC-3161](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3161)-compliant time-stamp servers that can be used free-of-charge. [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) can create RFC 3161 time-stamp requests and verify the responses.

Here is a simple Bash script that time-stamps a file using the [time-stamp server operated by StartSSL](https://startssl.com/?app=25#61):

```
in_file='[path to file]'  # name of file to be hashed and time-stamped
out_file="${in_file}.tsr"  # name of file to save the time-stamp response
ts_server='http://www.startssl.com/timestamp'  # URL of time-stamp server

# Use openssl to create the time-stamp request, then use curl to submit the request and save the response.
openssl ts -query -data "$in_file" -sha1 -cert |
curl -o "$out_file" -sSH 'Content-Type: application/timestamp-query' --data-binary @- "$ts_server"

# Verify the response.
openssl ts -verify -data "$in_file" -in "$out_file" -CApath "$(openssl version -d | cut -d '"' -f 2)/certs/"

# Print the response in human-readable format for more info.
openssl ts -reply -in "$out_file" -text
```

Example of command outputs:

```
$ echo 'This is an example.' > testfile

$ in_file='./testfile'
$ out_file="${in_file}.tsr"
$ ts_server='http://www.startssl.com/timestamp'

$ openssl ts -query -data "$in_file" -sha1 -cert |
> curl -o "$out_file" -sSH 'Content-Type: application/timestamp-query' --data-binary @- "$ts_server"

$ openssl ts -verify -data "$in_file" -in "$out_file" -CApath "$(openssl version -d | cut -d '"' -f 2)/certs/"
Verification: OK

$ openssl ts -reply -in "$out_file" -text
Status info:
Status: Granted.
Status description: unspecified
Failure info: unspecified

TST info:
Version: 1
Policy OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.23223.1.2.0
Hash Algorithm: sha1
Message data:
    0000 - a6 f1 53 80 1c 93 03 d7-3c a2 b4 3d 3b e6 2f 44   ..S.....<..=;./D
    0010 - c6 b6 64 76                                       ..dv
Serial number: 0x28DD7D
Time stamp: Jan  1 18:26:50 2014 GMT
Accuracy: 0x01 seconds, unspecified millis, unspecified micros
Ordering: no
Nonce: 0xB9943DF6F7CD5191
TSA: DirName:/CN=StartCom Time-Stamping Authority/O=StartCom Ltd. (Start Commercial Limited)
Extensions:
```

Given a copy of the original file along with the `*.tsr` response, anyone can verify that the authority time-stamped the hash of the file at the specified time.

On Windows, Microsoft's [SignTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764.aspx) can be used instead of OpenSSL.

Answer (score 2):

See http://TrueTimeStamp.org

- Free.
- Easy to manually time stamp files or a file's SHA256 hash.
- Easy API for automated time-stamping by calling

  - http://truetimestamp.org/submit.php?hash=YOUR_SHA256_IN_HEXADECIMAL_HERE
- Easy verification of time-stamps on the website by supplying the file or its hash.
- Supplies Certificates that can be verified even offline.
- Uses several ways to prove the time-stamp:

  - Stores time-stamps and hashes in its online database.
  - Digitally signed certificate using PKI.
  - Sequentially linked hashes.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?