# Which organization is responsible for certifying a TSA?

Tags: signature, timestamping

I see there a number of free TSA services according to [this page](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12647/a-timestamping-authority-digital-notary) (not all are still in service).

In other sources I see references to the requirement of audits for the TSA to be 'rfc3161 compliant'. Given the number of free services, not to mention the new blockchain services (which are similar but not exactly the same as rfc3161), I'm finding it difficult to imagine they have all spent money on getting audited and certified. (This may pose a problem if and when the timestamps are presented before a legal court and their validity addressed or refuted by the opposing party). I am curious to know for the U.S.:

1. Are audits performed by a specific organization or private contractor?
2. In the U.S., is there an organization responsible for issuing a 'seal of approval'?

Comment: It's not the US, but in Europe it appears [ETSI 319 421](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319400_319499/319421/01.01.01_60/en_319421v010101p.pdf) and [ETSI 319 422](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319400_319499/319422/01.01.01_60/en_319422v010101p.pdf) could be relevant here and I'd suppose if you ask nicely your standard audit company that also issues the standard CA audits can also audit for this. (Though I didn't have time yet to read through the standards to see if any specific body is mentioned for certification)

Comment: Sounds expensive... probably beyond the means of any "free TSA". My guess might have been NIST (although they are a non-authoritative organization) or maybe some organization for weights and measurements.