# Temporal or spatial digital signatures

Tags: public-key, signature, timestamping

Digital signatures allow authentication of content based on a secret held by the signing entity. Are there any existing schemes, proposals or even services for letting "location" or "time" sign the content?

Motivation: Time and space (i.e. geolocation) are fundamental variables in our lifes and their integration in digital signatures could be useful e.g. for impeding fake news or elaborating on new proof-of-** principles for the broader field of "blockchain"-like technologies.

Are there any existing third party services? Or are there even trustless approaches maybe based on distributed computing / p2p-networks / sealed hardware?

**Edit 1**: I now see there are already some topics dealing with centralized timestamping services (e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12647/65109)). Thus, the emphasis of this topic should be more directed towards trustless approaches.

Comment: I think it would be possible to add a second signature to confirm the geolocation. But I think it would also be pretty easy to fake this, i.e. with the use of TOR it's possible configure at least the country from where the exit node should be...

Comment: There are "Trusted Timestamping" services, where trusted 3rd parties (usually backed by a certificate authority) provides timespamping of documents.

Comment: Are you asking the time and location information will be in the signature?

Comment: @AleksanderRas: I agree, localization using IP address is not safe.

Comment: gusto2: thank you, added that information to the post. kelalaka: yes, I think it would be convenient to put that information into or near to the signature so a second party could check for it somehow